# Paypal IPN payment_status

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to use paypal ipn on my website. I am using sandbox to debug it...
I noticed sometimes I get values on payment_status like pending ...
My question is, do I get a response again from paypal ipn when this payment becomes complete?

Comment: maybe better addressed to paypal tech support?

Comment: I was thinking on that, but here is faster, I think...

Comment: give a man a fish, he eats for a day. teach a man to fish, .....

Comment: @KevinDTimm I really don't see why you are being like that. He is right, it's faster. And it can help others, like myself. Don't be "that guy"

Comment: It was two years ago, he didn't accept any answers and the second answer he received pointed him back to Paypal (as an answer, not a comment).  I'm not that guy, I'm the guy who points out to him (and others when they come here to look) that you need to check the appropriate locations first, then come to SO when those are exhausted.  Learning how to use support and search engines is the most important part of SW development.  If you can't do that, you are always at the mercy of q&a.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do. That is the reason why you should implement logic in your code to cope for multiple messages relating to the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

From paypal site: https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_testing_SBOverview

"The PayPal Sandbox is a self-contained environment within which you can prototype and test PayPal features and APIs. The PayPal Sandbox is an almost identical copy of the live PayPal website"

Comparison table in the link above does mention some scenarios like Fraud detection are not enabled in sandbox.

Other than these, it should be safer to assume that features of live are same in sandbox ( like receiving IPN after status change from pending to complete etc).